# Model categories as a tool to resolve size issues for localizing categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, localization

I have a rather basic question about one motivation for introducing *model categories* in David White's [notes](http://personal.denison.edu/%7Ewhiteda/files/Lecture%20Notes/Localization,%20Universal%20Properties,%20and%20Homotopy%20Theory%20%28GSS%29.pdf), as a possible way to overcome troubles with size issues appearing when localizing a category $C$ at certain class of morphisms $W$ to obtain $C[W^{-1}]$ whose homs might not neccessarily form a set but rather a proper class.

Could somebody elaborate on how precisely working with model categories resolves this problem? Even though this question seems rather natural to ask, almost all sources dealing with model categories that I've read so far introduced these axiomatically ... refering at most to the historic part that one tries more or less "to mimic literally" the procedure to turn category of topological spaces into homotopy category via introducing distinguished classes of maps. But this does not seem to immediately address the point on solving size issues that David White mentions in the linked notes.

Comment: You form the homotopy category of a model category $\mathcal{M}$ by taking the full subcategory of $\mathcal{M}$ spanned by all the fibrant-cofibrant objects, then modding out by an equivalence relation (homotopy) on morphisms. Both of those operations--passing to the full subcat, and modding out the equiv. rel.--make the category SMALLER, not BIGGER. So the homotopy category doesn't have size issues like the Gabriel-Zisman localization: the hom-sets can't "blow up" into proper classes. But the homotopy category still succeeds in inverting the weak equivalences (between fib-cofib. objects).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess I'm the canonical person to answer this question. I wrote those notes as a PhD student, a long time ago, to go along with a talk I was giving at a grad student conference. They were basically my lecture notes, written for myself. I have learned a lot since then, and would probably write things differently today. While having a model structure *does* allow you to solve the size issues, it is not *necessary* for doing so. In answering this question, I learned that a similar question, also pointing to my old seven-page lecture note, [was asked on MSE four years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271736/how-do-model-categories-assist-in-localizing-at-the-weak-equivalences). That question quotes me as saying "Attempting to get around these set-theoretic issues leads you to model categories." Today, I'd stop short of that claim. Yes, model categories are one solution to the size problem, but they are not the only solution, and I don't think you're "naturally led" to them unless you set out to mimic the construction of the homotopy category of topological spaces.

A better motivation for why you'd want a model category $M$ is that it gives you *control* over the hom spaces in the homotopy category $Ho M$. Let $X,Y\in M$ and let $\gamma: M\to HoM$ the canonical functor. Let $Q$ denote cofibrant replacement, $R$ denote fibrant replacement, and $\sim$ denote the homotopy relation. [Mark Hovey's book](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf) contains the Fundamental Theorem of Model Categories (Theorem 1.2.10), which states that $M(QX,RY)/\sim \cong Ho M(\gamma X, \gamma Y)$. Hence, if you have a model structure, it is much easier to compute hom sets in the homotopy category. Thanks to this theorem, if $M$ is locally small (i.e., has a set of morphisms between any two objects) then so is $HoM$, because we have just identified $Ho M(\gamma X, \gamma Y)$ as a quotient of a set.

To answer [Maxime's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463828/model-categories-as-a-tool-to-resolve-size-issues-for-localizing-categories/463832#comment1204287_463832), let me describe the context for my talk in 2012. This was back in the era when some folks were advocating to do away with model categories entirely and do everything $\infty$-categorically. It was before your time, but you might enjoy watching sparks fly at the MO thread ["Do we still need model categories?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78400/do-we-still-need-model-categories) and other back-and-forth exchanges on many other threads in that era, between the same participants. My point in the first version of this answer was that the size motivation was not *convincing* to the audience because they responded with "hey, wait, $\infty$-categories also have locally small homotopy categories, so I guess we don't need model categories for this." I know that you, Maxime, know this, but let me spell it out for other readers. If $C$ is a [quasi-category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-category), then by definition it is a simplicial set satisfying a certain lifting condition. Its morphisms are the 1-simplices so it's automatically locally small. Its homotopy category is again locally small.

Another reason that the audience was not convinced by the size motivation is that one can also start out from a [relative category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+category) or a [category with weak equivalences](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+with+weak+equivalences) $(C,W)$, which is much less structure than a model category requires, construct its homotopy category, then try to prove the homotopy category is locally small. One method of doing this is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809608/how-to-construct-a-quasi-category-from-a-category-with-weak-equivalences). The idea is to apply hammock localization to get to a simplicially enriched category, then apply $\pi_0$ to get to the homotopy category of $(C,W)$, and it'll often be locally small. A worthwhile paper to read is [Function complexes in homotopical algebra](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938380900257) by Dwyer and Kan. They start out by describing the hammock localization $L^H(C,W)$ for the situation when $C$ is a small category, but then they point out in 3.3 that they can do the same even when $C$ is not small, by way of a theory of *homotopically small* simplicial sets, meaning that $\pi_n(X)$ is small for all $n$, even if $X$ is not a small simplicial set. As far as I know, they only show that in the examples they care about, the simplicial category they get from $C$ is homotopically small, and do not provide general conditions on $C$ to guarantee this.

ASIDE: For the set-theoretically minded, a reasonable question is "Can quasi-categories actually model non-small settings?" or "What's the quasi-category associated to a non-small model category?" Usually folks in the $\infty$-category world get around these questions by way of Grothendieck universes. This means "small" now refers to a $U$-small set, and by fixing a sufficiently large universe $U$, formerly "large" categories become small categories. For example, Lennart Meier's paper [Fibration Categories are Fibrant Relative Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02036) constructs a functor from the category of small relative categories to the category of (necessarily small) quasi-categories. Then he applies this functor to the relative category underlying a model category. What if the model category is not small? Meier has a footnote on page 7 stating that universes can get around this kind of objection. In Lurie's Higher Topos Theory the language of universes is similarly invoked. This use of universes might not be satisfying to the OP, because we could have applied that to the motivating problem in the first place and just used Gabriel-Zisman localization. Quillen would not have been satisfied with an answer of "just increase the size of $U$." The trick is to construct the homotopy category of a locally small category $C$, with a chosen class of morphisms $W$, and get a locally small homotopy category with respect to the same Grothendieck universe. As is pointed out in [Homotopy Limit Functors on Model Categories and Homotopical Categories](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/dhks.pdf) by Dwyer, Kan, Hirschhorn, and Smith, "the homotopy category of a locally small homotopical category need not also be locally small." You really do need conditions on $(C,W)$ or you need to change the question being asked by increasing the size of the Grothendieck universe.

Anyway, coming back to the motivating question, a good example to share with the audience is Example 4.15 of Krause's "[Localization theory for triangulated categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1324.pdf)," a derived category that is not locally small. This shows that the issue can be subtle. Model categories provide an excellent way to get control over the hom sets of $HoM$, but $\infty$-categorical techniques can also be used to show that $HoC$ is locally small, for sufficiently nice $C$ (requiring less of $C$ than a full model structure). More details about why the homotopy category of a model category is locally small can be found in [this nice blog post](https://grossack.site/2022/07/11/model-categories.html).

Comment: I'm confused, I think a relative cateory is not enough to resolve size issues. In particular, model categories *are* a particularly good way to ensure that the hom sets are small

Comment: I'm probably just missing something in your comment, but it seems like you are saying that there is a theorem which says "The homotopy category of a locally small relative category is locally small." Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I edited. Of course, I do agree that model categories are a good way to ensure the hom sets are small, but I provided detail about why the audience (very pro $\infty$-categories and a bit anti model categories) were not satisfied. Essentially, their POV was that quasi-categories or relative categories (plus a generous helping of universes) resolved all size issues. I tend to disagree and added more detail about the pros and cons of that approach.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I edited to add the best reference I know, which is a Dwyer-Kan paper. It stops short of that precise statement, and the DKHS book suggests it's not true (or, at least, not true if you say "homotopical category" instead of "relative category"). Of course, you can MAKE it true by changing the Grothendieck universe, but if we refuse to change universes then I think it's not true. In particular, you at least need a 3-arrow calculus assumption, and likely more. But, I do agree with critics that you don't need a full model structure.

Comment: let me try to summarize how I understood roughly the point (...but I will try to avoid or at least to black box the $\infty$-categoretical issues because originally posting this question I not intended to digress in this direction even as I see a posteriori that these provide also a way to solve the size problems I'm concerned with...)

Comment: So the the initial problem is that we start with certain category $C$ and take certain class of morphisms there $W$ and want to associate to it a category where these become invertible. The Gabriel-Zisman construction $C[W^{-1}]$, which we also should can **the homotopy category** wrt $W$ solves this problem, but has a drawback these size issues.

Comment: Thus the goal is to find another category $H(C)$ which we can "naturally" associate to $C$ as far possible which is **weakly equivalent** to  $C[W^{-1}]$, which we also should call "homotopy category" of $C$, and which in contrast to the latter has no size issues. Sidenote: so far I understand the concept of the notion of **"homotopy category" of $C$** it is welldefined up to equivalence, ie one calls any category equivalent to   $C[W^{-1}]$ "homotopy category of $C$", is it correct?

Comment: If what I wrote so far is correct, now let's ask how one could find such one. A model category $M_C$ of $C$ is certain structure, which is essentially $C$ with certain extra data, which we need to specify additionally, ie it's not provided intrinsically by $C$, solves the problem in the way user509184 in the comment above or in the blog post you gave the link of at end is described, by fibrant-cofibrant replacement techniques, and at the end of the day we get from it a homotopy category $Ho(M_C)$ which is equivalent to $C[W^{-1}]$ but hasn't the size issue anymore.

Comment: But so far I understand you correctly, to resolve the size issues **only** the model category has to much redundant structure, so is a bit "over the top", therefore we can instead try to start with a weaker structure $(C,W)$ (...having $C$ still as "unterlying" category) like relative cat or cat with weak equiv's (or if we have already our model cat, then descent via forgetful functor to one of these properly weaker structures) and apply the techniques you explained.

Comment: At the end of the day we obtain a "further homotopy category" $H(C,W)$ - as before it is still equivalent to  $C[W^{-1}]$, therefore it's legal to call it still the homotopy category of original $C$, but the advantage is  -at least in much broader cases as for  $C[W^{-1}]$- in contrast this  $H(C,W)$ has no size issues anymore.

Comment: So summarizingly, what we are lookng for if we start with cat $C$ and want to invert certain class of morhisms $W$ there, we are looking for additional structure $(C,W')$ having $C$ as undelying, to which we can naturally associate a locally small cat $H(C,W')$ which is weakly equivalent to $C[W^{-1}]$, so another "legal pretendent" for homotopy cat of $C$, but without size issues. But how to construct this $H(C,W')$ involves of course plethora of methds - also strongly involving $\infty$-cat as your example show. Does what I wrote so far rephrase the issue in low level terms correctly so far?

Comment: @user267839 The homotopy category is well-defined up to equivalence of categories. It must satisfy the universal property of admitting a functor from $C$ sending all morphisms in $W$ to isomorphisms. I'd say $C[W^{-1}]$ is equivalent to $Ho(C)$ rather than "weakly equivalent" since the latter might depend on a choice of notion of weak equivalence of categories. I think everything else you wrote is fine, except some authors (like DKHS) don't even insist $H(C,W')$ is locally small, which allows them to require even less of $(C,W)$, namely a "homotopical category."