# A model category of spaces where strict commutative monoids are $E_\infty$-spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

There are various strict monoidal model categories of spectra (e.g. symmetric spectra) where the honestly commutative monoid objects model the "coherently commutative" ring spectra (which might otherwise be expressed using, say, operads). Is there an analog for spaces? That is, there a monoidal model category, Quillen equivalent to spaces (in some monoidal sense), such that the category of commutative monoids in this category is (Quillen) equivalent to the category of algebras in spaces over some fixed and suitably free $E_\infty$-operad? In spaces, this is false; topological abelian groups are very far from modelling infinite loop spaces.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question. What do you mean by asking that the commutative monoid objects model the ''coherently commutative'' ring spectra? Also, by ''coherently commutative'' do you just mean $E_\infty$? Certainly strictly commutative monoids are $E_\infty$-objects. Are you asking when these two concepts are exactly the same? If so, I believe the way to phrase this in terms of operads is to say that there is ''rectification'' between $Com$ and $E_\infty$. See for example the paper of Casacuberta, et al on Coloured operads

Comment: Another question: you ask that the category of commutative monoids be (Quillen) equivalent to the category of algebras over some $E_\infty$ operad. In order to get a Quillen equivalence you'd need a model category structure. Why should the category of commutative monoids be a model category? It seems to me that this is a very restrictive hypothesis (and it's highly related to my current work), but maybe it's easy for Top. If so, I'd like to hear about it!

Comment: @David: I mean "$E_\infty$" by "coherently commutative" (or any of the essentially equivalent concepts, e.g. commutative monoid objects in the $\infty$-categorical sense. I'll have to look at the paper of Casacuberta. 

Comment: I think there are certain conditions when one gets a model structure on commutative monoid objects. It seems that there is a model structure on commutative monoid objects in certain cases, according to 4.3.2.1 in DAG III. I didn't really have anything too precise in mind when I referred to commutative monoids; all I meant was that there are plenty of infinite loop spaces which are not topological abelian groups or monoids. 

Comment: @Akhil: When you say $E_\infty$ do you just require that the diagrams commute up to homotopy and the coherence diagrams for those homotopies commute up to homotopy, etc? This may be different from what operad people mean by $E_\infty$ but I'm not sure. Thanks for the DAG reference. It doesn't apply here because Top is not combinatorial, but maybe something else does. The question of when $Monoids(M)$ is a model category is addressed in "Algebras and Modules in Monoidal Model Categories." It seems much harder to get a model structure on $CommMonoids(M)$, and this is something I do in my thesis.

Comment: @David: I guess I mean "algebra over an $E_\infty$-operad" -- I definitely want more than something in the homotopy category (i.e. a homotopy commutative H space). Yes, it does seem that constructing model structures on commutative monoid objects is quite difficult. For instance, Tyler Lawson gave a nice argument that this can't be done for cdgas in characteristic $p$: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23269/non-examples-of-model-structures-that-fail-for-subtle-surprising-reasons/23885#23885   

Comment: @Akhil: I finally found time to read that section in DAG and just wanted to say thanks for the reference! It turns out to be quite related to what I'm doing right now and it would have been bad if I'd continued without realizing it was there. What I'm working on should be another way to get that same result but with different hypotheses. If you hear of anything else Lurie has done regarding the model category of commutative monoids, please let me know. Tyler's answer to that other question is also interesting, and will also probably get a mention in the "previous work" section of my thesis.

Comment: @David: Glad to have been helpful! I'd be curious to eventually read it and learn more about this stuff...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, such a model is developed in a paper of Blumberg, Cohen and Schlichtkrull about Thom spectra.

Answer (score 5):

You may also be interested in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1092).

Comment: This paper by Lind indeed compares different approaches, in particular $\ast$-modules and $\mathcal{I}$-spaces. The latter have been considered earlier by Schlichtkrull and in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.2764.pdf Sagave and Schlichtkrull give a more direct proof of the equivalence of commutative monoids in $\mathcal{I}$-spaces with algebras over the Barrat-Eccles operad.