# What do we know about the homotopy of $\mathrm{Q}S^0\wedge\mathrm{Q}S^0$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The homotopy groups of $\mathrm{Q}S^0$ are the stable homotopy groups of spheres, of which we know the [first 81 exactly, and the first 90 up to some uncertainties](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04511). A table is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table_of_stable_homotopy_groups):
[image]

Do we know what are the first few homotopy groups of the smash product $\mathrm{Q}S^0\wedge\mathrm{Q}S^0$?

Comment: My apologies for not being able to formulate this question more precisely; I'm pretty sure it can be done, and I tried my best to do so...

Comment: I think your question is confusing two different tensor products. $S^0$ is the unit for the smash product of pointed sets, which is also the coproduct of commutative monoids therein. The tensor product described by Martin Brandenburg has unit $\mathbb N_+$. These are respectively the pointed analogues of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ on unpointed commutative monoids.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Oh, gosh, you're right!

Comment: @MarcHoyois By the way, is there an analogue of the tensor product $\otimes_0$ in the setting of commutative monoids in pointed spaces, and also of $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{N}_+$?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really understand this pointed tensor product. The analogue of $\mathbb N$ however is the groupoid of finite sets, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401181/tensor-products-of-mathbbe-infty-spaces

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thanks!