# Reference request - CDGA vs. sAlg in char. 0

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories, simplicial-stuff, differential-graded-algebras

Hello,

Are the model categories of simplicial commutative algebras over $k$ and that of commutative differential graded algebras (in negative cohmological dimension) Quillen equivalent in char. 0 (or maybe if $k$ is a $Q$-algebra)? What would be a reference?

Thank you

Comment: If $k$ is a characteristic zero ring, the normalized chain complex functor is a right Quillen equivalence between commutative simplicial $k$-algebras and connective commutative differential graded $k$-algebras, each equipped with their projective model structure. The proof is described in Quillen's _Rational Homotopy Theory_, p. 223. See also Bousfield-Gugenheim. (This critically uses characteristic zero, of course; in characteristic $p$, the homology of a commutative simplicial algebra admits a divided power structure.)

Comment: Is the only difference between the two that a cdga is strictly graded commutative whereas a commutative simplicial algebra is commutative in an $E_\infty$ sense? Or is there something more to it?

Answer (score 4):

I think Proposition 8.1.4.11 of Lurie's Higher Algebra gives the equivalence between (negatively graded, or homologically positively graded) CDGA's and connective $E_\infty$ algebras and Proposition 8.1.4.20 does the same for simplicial algebras (search for "rational numbers").

Comment: Thank you, but I could not locate 7.1.4.20 at all. Maybe you can write the names of section/subsection/etc. (maybe there are several versions with different numbering).

Comment: that's odd O_o I can see it just fine in the May 18, 2011 version. (I originally dug it up by searching "rational numbers")

Comment: OK, thank you. It seems that in the most updated version, one should replace your "7" by "8".

Comment: sorry, my bad. I was clicking on the link google was providing, which was an older version of the book.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the paper by Mike Mandell titled : Topological Andre-Quillen Cohomology and $E_{\infty}$ Andre-Quillen Cohomology. I am pretty sure his statements do not require a 
characteristic 0 assumption. For example, Theorem 1.3 on page 6 might be of interest.

Sorry, I guess I forgot to mention some things. I was initially pointed to this by Shipley's paper on $H\mathbb{Z}$ algebras and DGAs. The point is that when you want to remove the characteristic zero assumption you need to remember the $E_{\infty}$ algebra structure. In characteristic zero, it has to be essentially unique. This is related to the fact that the (co)homology of the symmetric groups is usually torsion. I remember Akhil Mathew asking a question related to this a while back. Anyways, the characteristic result follows. Although, it was known prior to this, see Clark Barwick's comment.

Comment: Yes, one reason you need to move to $E_\infty$ in characteristic $\neq 0$ is that you have no hope of having a model category on strictly commutative monoids unless the characteristic is 0. This means you need to use $E_\infty$ if you want homotopy theoretic meaning. See for instance: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23269/non-examples-of-model-structures-that-fail-for-subtle-surprising-reasons/23885#23885